# Add Azure/Facebook authentication to ionic 2/cordova/angular 2 app?

Tags: cordova, azure, ionic-framework, ionic2, azure-mobile-services

I'm following this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users) to add Azure/Facebook authentication to ionic 2 app.

In the step (3), there is

> Open the www/js/index.js file for editing, locate the onDeviceReady() method, and under the client creation code add the following code:

However, I cannot find the file `www/js/index.js` in scaffold ionic 2 project. Which file I should modify? And only the files under `app` are supposed to be modified? Is there any step by step documentation to add the Azure authentication for ionic 2 app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `onDeviceReady` code in `app.component.ts` inside `platform.ready()`

```
export class MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    }
  }
}
```

For adding `Facebook` authentication `ionic-native` provides support for the cordova plugin.  Check [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/) out. Its easy to setup.

```
let permissions = ["public_profile","email"];
Facebook.login(permissions)
.then( (response) => {
  let token = { access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken };
  return token;
}).catch( this.handleError);
```

For `azure` cordova has a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps) which you can try. I have not tried it.